# Open command line in C# and send commands PuTTY or KiTTY

Tags: c#, .net, ssh, command-line, putty

I want to open the Command line from C# from GUI, and send this line:

```
kitty.exe abc@192.19.35.80 -load file -l name -pass pswrd -cmd "echo 123"
```

This is to actually open the KiTTY (which is a port of PuTTY) and send the command `echo 123` (which is just an example) to the SSH.

I couldn't find any way doing it in C#.

Comment: See also [Run Unix commands using PuTTY in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27592329/850848).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
System.Diagnostics.Process cmd = new System.Diagnostics.Process();

cmd.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe";
cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
cmd.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

cmd.Start();

cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("kitty.exe abc@192.19.35.80 -load file -l name -pass pswrd -cmd \"echo 123\"");
```

Something along those lines should get you in the right direction.  You will need to adjust the call in the `cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine` to point to `kitty.exe` location.  Or you could directly call `kitty.exe` as the process instead of `cmd.exe` and use the `StartInfo.Arguments`.

Also to note that if you are just needing the Command Line Interface of `Putty` then you should investigate `Plink` as it is the Command Line Version of `Putty`.

Comment: Thanks, I don't want to use plink as I want to see the Shell open all time, and as I understood Plink works in the background (is it true?)