# Run Unix commands using PuTTY in C#

Tags: c#, .net, ssh, putty

I am trying to run Unix commands in PuTTY using C#. I have the below code. But the code is not working. I am not able to open PuTTY.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Process cmd = new Process();
    cmd.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\cmd";
    cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = false;
    cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    cmd.Start();
    cmd.StartInfo.Arguments = "C:\Users\win7\Desktop\putty.exe -ssh mahi@192.168.37.129 22 -pw mahi";
}
```

Comment: You've gone a bit wrong there mate. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147203/automating-running-command-on-linux-from-windows-using-putty

Answer (score 8):

*First, in general, you better use native .NET SSH library, like SSH.NET, instead of running external application.*

*See [How to run commands on SSH server in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30883237/850848#44797940)*

---

- The `putty.exe` is a GUI application. It's intended to interactive use, not for automation. There's no point trying to redirect its standard output, as it's not using it.
- For automation, use another tool from PuTTY package, the [`plink.exe`](https://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter7.html).
  It's a console application, so you can redirect its standard output/input.
- There's no point trying to execute an application indirectly via the `cmd.exe`. Execute it directly.
- You need to redirect standard input too, to be able to feed commands to the Plink.
- You have to provide arguments before calling the `.Start()`.
- You may want to redirect error output too (the `RedirectStandardError`). Though note that you will need to read output and error output in parallel, what complicates the code.

---

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Process cmd = new Process();
    cmd.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\plink.exe";
    cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    cmd.StartInfo.Arguments = "-ssh mahi@192.168.37.129 22 -pw mahi";
    cmd.Start();
    cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("./myscript.sh");
    cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("exit");
    string output = cmd.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ProcessStartInfo cmd = new ProcessStartInfo();
        cmd.FileName = @"C:\Users\win7\Desktop\putty.exe";
        cmd.UseShellExecute = false;
        cmd.RedirectStandardInput = false;
        cmd.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        cmd.Arguments = "-ssh mahi@192.168.37.129 22 -pw mahi";
        using (Process process = Process.Start(cmd))
        {
            process.WaitForExit();
        }
    }
```

Comment: While the code indeed executes PuTTY, how does it allow you to execute commands?

Comment: If you want to run commands, I'd recommend using an SSH library like [SSH.NET](http://sshnet.codeplex.com/) versus using putty.