# Authenticating serial connection in Plink

Tags: serial-port, putty, plink

I have a wifi module that I need to communicate with over serial connection.  It requires a user/password to authenticate.  Is this possible to achieve using Plink?  here is what I am trying to do:

```
plink -v -serial COM7 -l yyyy -pw xxxx -sercfg 115000,8,1,n,N -m Display.txt
```

This is not working.  The `-pw` is only allowed with SSH.

If I remove the `-pw` and run it I get this:

```
Opening serial device COM7
Configuring baud rate 115000
blah blah blah
```

The problem is, when I press <kbd>enter</kbd>, it then prompts for user which I specified in the command.  Then it asks for the password.  Then command in `Display.txt` never gets executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no authentication in serial connection.

If you are getting prompted for username and password, these are prompts that are part of the session. They are not some specific authentication prompts that PuTTY can automatically answer with username and password specified in advance.

Feed the responses to the prompts from a redirected standard input:

```
(
    rem Simulate the initial Enter
    echo.
    echo username
    echo password
    echo command
) | plink -v -serial COM7 -sercfg 115000,8,1,n,N
```

---

You will also probably need to terminate the Plink somehow:
[Send commands via COM port using plink and exit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70473206/850848)