# Send commands via COM port using plink and exit

Tags: windows, batch-file, serial-port, plink

I need to execute one or more commands via COM port (from console) on an embedded Linux device.
I am trying to use plink on a Windows machine but it doesn't work.

I've tried different cases, one of them is:

```
echo "mkdir /test" | plink -batch -serial \\\\.\\com4 -sercfg 115200,N,8 -l root
```

I have a couple of problems:

1. hangs until you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, after that you will have *"login:"*, and will not exit
2. the command doesn't work (doesn't create a dir)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use `echo.` to send empty line = <kbd>Enter</kbd>
2. Another `echo` to send the login
3. In Windows (contrary to *nix shells), if you do `echo "foo"`, you get `"foo"`, not `foo`. So you might need `echo mkdir ...`, not `echo "mkdir ..."`.
4. You will need to kill the session somehow. There's no *signal* you can send to `plink` to close it. And as the serial connection is not really a connection, it cannot be closed remotely (the way an SSH server can close the connection, when you send an `exit` command). So all you can probably do is to kill the `plink`, e.g. using [`taskkill`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/taskkill).

```
(
  echo.
  echo username
  echo mkdir /test
  timeout /t 5 > nul
  taskkill /f /im plink.exe > nul
) | plink ...
```