# Send commands via serial connection using plink from bash script and exit

Tags: bash, scripting, serial-port, plink, petalinux

I'm writing a bash script on a Windows machine that enters a PetaLinux machine over a serial connection, performs some commands, and *should* exit back to the bash script to continue performing commands. I'm unable to exit back to the bash script so far.

Here is what I have tried:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Running board bring up script"

BOARD_A_SERIAL_PORT="COM22"

plink -serial "$BOARD_A_SERIAL_PORT" -sercfg 115200,8,n,1,X -batch <<EOF
root
root
sleep 2
ps aux | grep plink
ps aux | grep plink
killall -9 plink
ps aux | grep [p]link
exit
EOF

echo 'script successfully exited' #never reached. the serial terminal hangs
```

Answer (score 0):

You are running the `killall` on the remote server. But you need to run it locally.

Here is an example how to achieve this in Windows batch file:
[Send commands via COM port using plink and exit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70473206/850848)
It shows how to run the `taskkill` locally, while the `plink` in running. The key point is not to provide a static input via heredoc [`<<EOF`], but use a subshell [the `( )`]. The subshell allows you to both produce the input using `echo` commands, but also to run the `sleep` and `killall` locally.

Translating that Widows batch file to Linux/bash tools and adjusting to your needs, you can do something like:

```
(
  echo root
  echo root
  echo your_command
  sleep 2
  killall -9 plink
) | plink -serial "$BOARD_A_SERIAL_PORT" -sercfg 115200,8,n,1,X -batch

echo 'script successfully exited'
```

Not tested. Plus, I'm not a bash expert, and I'm sure there's more elegant way to achieve this in bash.