# How do I use plink to connect to a serial port with a named pipe address?

Tags: serial-port, pipe, putty, plink

The putty is configurable via gui to simply connect to a piped serial port, but I can't find a command line way to do it on plink's documentation!

Would like to provide a command line example that can connect to a named pipe serial port via the command line. Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40877804/850848

Comment: @MartinPrikryl
It doesn't work either. I'm using it \\.\pipe\serial (or \\\\. \\pipe\\serial) to replace the COM1 parameter, but it says "access denied" or "specified path not found".

It is possible to access it through the putty configuration name.

Comment: Provide us all info you have IN your question. Including your PuTTY configuration and Plink attempts.