# Open a PuTTY window via Python subprocess.Popen (or Paramiko session) and run number of shell commands (like "top") in the same window

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssh, subprocess, putty

I want to open a PuTTY window, login to some server and enter few commands right after that and at the end save the output. I want to see the PuTTY window open and all activity that I am doing via program (hence need PuTTY GUI).

Here is what I have tried:
I am able to open a new window and login in it. But using `stdin.write` I am not able to enter further commands in the same window. What am I doing wrong here? I am very new to python. Please help.

```
import subprocess
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

p = subprocess.Popen("putty.exe demo@Test.Rebex.Net -pw password", stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
p.stdin.write("ls".encode("utf-8"))
print(p.stdout.readlines())
```

I have tried Paramiko, and don't want to use it, as it fails to display/print the output of commands like `top`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PuTTY is a GUI application, it does not use a standard input. It is  not intended for automation. For automation, you can use Plink, what is a console equivalent of PuTTY.
See also [Pipe PuTTY console to Python script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28311315/850848)

---

Though you should use Paramiko. It does not *fail to display/print the output of commands like "top"*. It' not what it is for. You have to attach it to a terminal to achieve what you want. See [Running interactive commands in Paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/q/373639/850848).

Or for automation, you better run the `top` non-interactively. See your other question [Collect output from top command using Paramiko in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65993207/850848).