# Pass command to KiTTY UI

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssh, putty

I wish to automate the below task

1. Launch KiTTY
2. Enter username and password
3. Login successfully
4. Enter this below command to see the logs

```
tail -2000f /apps/test/good.log
```

I am able to achieve up to point 3 using below code

```
from subprocess import Popen
Popen("powershell kitty-0.73.1.1.exe sakthi@x.y.w.z -pw YYYY")
```

(new KiTTY windows is opened and user is logged in successfully)

But I don't know how to pass the below command

```
tail -2000f /apps/test/good.log
```

Note: 
I am using Python3

*I WANT THIS AUTOMATION AT UI LEVEL*. I have around 5 to 6 log files to go through while testing. I don't want to open all the logs manually. So I am looking for a way to automate it.

I am using KiTTY, because it can re-connect automatically when there is any network problem.

Comment: You're asking a slightly different question, but the answer is the same https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163542/python-how-do-i-pass-a-string-into-subprocess-popen-using-the-stdin-argument

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - How do I pass a string into subprocess.Popen (using the stdin argument)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163542/python-how-do-i-pass-a-string-into-subprocess-popen-using-the-stdin-argument)

Comment: Why do you run PowerShell from Python to run yet another application? + Why do you even run an application to execute a command on an SSH server? Use a native Python SSH module, like Paramiko. And you won't have this kind of problems.

Comment: @Grismar I want this automation at UI level.

Comment: @KandanSiva please look into the provided link - streaming in character data on stdin equates to a user typing the data on that stream. Unless you think there is a timing issue (where the application reads the stream before it should), this should be the solution you're after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

KiTTY, as well as PuTTY, has `-m` command-line switch to provide a command for SSH "exec" channel.
This is discussed in: [Automating command/script execution using PuTTY](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39361444/850848)

KiTTY additionally has [`-cmd` command-line switch](https://www.9bis.net/kitty/#!pages/CommandLine.md), which (contrary to `-m`) simulates key strokes on SSH "shell" channel. It is an equivalent of [KiTTY "Automatic Command" feature](https://www.9bis.net/kitty/#!pages/AutomaticCommand.md).
See also [Open command line in C# and send commands PuTTY or KiTTY](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22536723/850848)

---

Though if you want to *automate* testing, you better use a native Python SSH module, like [Paramiko](https://www.paramiko.org/).

Comment: If you have a new question, please post it as a new question. This is Q&A site, not a chat.